# Is there any difference between buying Frozen Synapse: Red on Steam or the developer site?

Tags: frozen-synapse, frozen-synapse-red

I already own Frozen Synapse the base game on Steam, and with the newly released DLC Frozen Synapse: RED I wonder whether to buy it on Steam, or pick it up directly at the [website of the developer](http://frozensynapse.com).

Is there a difference between the two shops (content or price wise)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buying Frozen Synapse, either on Steam or from the developer's web site, gets you a key code for the DLC.

No matter how you download the DLC, you must activate it by running Frozen Synapse and pressing the "Activate DLC" button to paste in the code.

In addition, you can take the FS Red DLC code and activate it in Steam by going to Games->Activate A Product On Steam.

**Whether you buy through Steam or through the developer's web site, you get a code that can be entered in FS and also added to Steam.**

If you purchase from Mode 7's web site, the developers get more of the money!

From IRC (Omroth is Ian Hardingham, the lead developer):

> ```
> (23:23:05) Goateh: Omroth! does it make a difference if i buy the dlc 
>   through steam or through your site?
> (23:23:54) Omroth: more money via us
> (23:24:00) Omroth: and you can activate it on steam :P
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there any source for 'the developers get more of the money!' ? I mean it would make sense..

Comment: @TimothyRoy Indeed - I saw the dev say so in their chat room.  I added the quote to the answer!

Answer (score 1):

The content is the same. For me the price is the same too, but that may depend on your region (I'm from mainland Europe, UK and US often have to pay less, Australia and Canada more).

Steam offers more payment options. Neither Frozen Synapse nor its DLC are in the ['Which retail CD Keys are accepted on Steam?'-List](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-WUSF-3601), so I can't say if a copy you buy from the developers website activates and downloads through steam.

Buying from the developers website might be better for them because Steam takes a cut of every sale. But since they use an external payment provider and I have no way of knowing if they take a higher/lower/equal percentage I can't say.

Comment: The developers have said that you can activate the dlc bought from their website on Steam.